# Some images not being displayed

Tags: html, css

For some reason I have 2 images that are not being displayed. They exist and I've tested others on there place at they don't work in this location (shown below)

```
<div id="the_pic">
<img  class="center fit right " src="WEB11.jpg"border="0" > 
<img  class="center fit right " src="text_top1.jpg"border="0" > 
<img  class="center fit right" src="WEB14.jpg"border="0" >
<img id="Bot"  class="center fit right" src="WEB10.jpg"border="0" >
<img  class="center fit right" src="WEB13.jpg"border="0" >
<img  id="Bot1" class="center fit right" src="WEB15.jpg"border="0" >    
<img  class="center fit right " src="WEB12.jpg"border="0" >
<img  class="center fit right " src="bottom_image.png"border="0" >     
<img  class="center fit right " src="WEB01.jpg"border="0" > 
<img  class="center fit right " src="text_middle.png"border="0" > 
<img  class="center fit right " src="WEB04.jpg"border="0" >
<img  class="center fit right " src="text_middle1.png"border="0" >  
<img  class="center fit right " src="111.jpg"border="0" > 
<img  class="center fit right " src="222.jpg"border="0" > 
<img  class="center fit right " src="666.jpg"border="0" > 
<img  class="center fit right " src="888.jpg"border="0" > 
<img  class="center fit right " src="777.jpg"border="0" > 
<img  class="center fit right " src="WEB02.jpg"border="0" > 
<img  class="center fit right " src="333.jpg"border="0" > 
<img  class="center fit right " src="999.jpg"border="0" > 
<img  class="center fit right " src="WEB08.jpg"border="0" > 
<img  class="center fit right " src="WEB09.jpg"border="0" >  

</div>
```

The two I'm having problems with are

```
<img  class="center fit right " src="111.jpg"border="0" > 
<img  class="center fit right " src="222.jpg"border="0" >
```

Comment: First of all you should self close the *img* tag.

Comment: @Sachin not a compulsion

Comment: can you please create a fiddle

Comment: try to clear your browser cache

Answer (score 1):

Well apart from not closing your `img` tags there does not seem to be anything wrong. Close the `img` tags like so

`<img src="image.jpg" alt="" title="" />`

Check you have the correct file extension, ie `.jpg` or `.jpeg`